# Application builds successfully but IntelliJ says my module does not read some other modules

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, java-platform-module-system

I am trying to create a multi-module project by using JPMS and Gradle multi-project functionalities. I have 3 modules for the testing: app, teacher and student. The student depends on the teacher and the app depends on both. Student and teacher modules have their own controller, service, entity, and repository. Each module has module-info.java file.

```java
module app {
    requires java.sql;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;

    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;

    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.context;

    requires teacher;
    requires student;

    opens az.chaypay.app to spring.core;
    exports az.chaypay.app to spring.beans, spring.context;
}

module teacher {
    requires static lombok;

    requires spring.web;

    exports az.chaypay.teacher to app;
    exports az.chaypay.teacher.api to student;
    exports az.chaypay.teacher.controller to spring.beans;
    exports az.chaypay.teacher.service.impl to spring.beans;

    opens az.chaypay.teacher.controller to spring.core;
    opens az.chaypay.teacher.repository.dao to spring.core, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind, org.hibernate.orm.core;
}

module student {
    requires static lombok;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;

    requires spring.web;

    exports az.chaypay.student to app;
    exports az.chaypay.student.controller to spring.beans;
    exports az.chaypay.student.service.impl to spring.beans;

    opens az.chaypay.student.controller to spring.core;
    opens az.chaypay.student.repository.dao to spring.core, com.fasterxml.jackson.databind, org.hibernate.orm.core;

    requires teacher;
}
```

When I run my application with these settings everything works. Applications are successfully built and run. But IntelliJ complains about imports.

[image]

> Package 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository' is declared in module 'spring.data.jpa', but module 'student' does not read it

I don't understand that if Java has a problem with imports then why does my application run without errors. Why does my application run without requires statement?

Comment: Please do not post images of code OR error messages.  Copy/paste the messages and format as code.

Comment: I don't think `spring-data-jpa` is a modular dependency, so it's available to you in the unnamed module.  Does the error go away if you *remove* the `requires spring.data.jpa` in the `app` module?

Comment: @DanielWiddis project stopped working after commenting `requires spring.data.jpa` line. I think the **student** module can use every module **app** module have required. But IDE is not able to understand that, maybe. The question is adding `requires spring.data.jpa` line to every module-info.java file does impact the performance of my project?

Comment: No it won't change the performance. It's imported exactly once in any case, this only impacts visibility.  And `student` won't see modules from `app` anyway, as the requires is the other way around.  In theory you *could* do `requires transitive spring.data.jpa` in the `teacher` module, and it would then be available to other modules that require it; but that's normally only done if you're just using the `teacher` API that exposes that requirement.  In your case you're directly using that import in `student` so you should explicitly add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it "seems" to work is that `spring-data-jpa` is not a modular dependency.  It can be included in a modular project using the automatic module name `spring.data.jpa`.

When you add the `requires spring.data.jpa` to the `app` module, it is available on the modulepath (with all its packages exported) in the unnamed module.

But once there, `student` can actually see that same unnamed module when you execute it, so it "happens" to work, but is incorrect.

Both your `app` and `student` modules depend on classes in the `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository` package, so the IntelliJ suggestion to add `requires spring.data.jpa` to the `student` module descriptor is correct.